# Pickle telethon message throws "cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object"

Tags: python, pickle, telegram, telethon, dill

```
messages = []

async def save_messages():
   async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
       async for msg in client.iter_messages(dialog):
           messages.append(msg)
           with open("data.db", 'wb') as f:
               pickle.dump(messages, f) # "TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object"
               print("saved to database")


client = TelegramClient('Session', config.api_id, config.api_hash)
client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(save_messages())
```

**Telethon** has a method named: [forward_message](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.forward_messages) by which I can forward message. I want to `save_messages` periodically (for example every 1 hour), and then forward saved messages at another time.

Neither **pickleDB** nor **dill** library can save message object:

> "TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object"

I read lots of related questions but none of them helped me. Do you have any idea? If this problem related to pickleDB, are there any libraries which don't have this issue?

Comment: did you find anyway for this action ?

Comment: I found a temporary solution. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet found any solution to dump telethon `Message` in the pickleDB, but as a temporary/alternative solution I can store the message id and the chat id (which the message belongs to):

```
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
   async for msg in client.iter_messages(dialog):
      db.save_message(msg.id, msg.chat.id)
```

And then forward that message with these two IDs

```
await client.forward_messages(entity, message_id, chat_id)
```